# How to get uuid of last inserted row using sqlx in postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I am inserting some data in table using SQLx like this

```
func (*RideRepositoryImpl) insert(entity interface{}, tx persistence.Transaction) (sql.Result, error) {
    ride := entity.(*model.Ride)

    placeHolders := repository.InsertPlaceholders(len(rideColumns))
    sql := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES(%s)", TableName, strings.Join(Columns, ","), placeHolders)
    return tx.Exec(sql, ride.ID.String(), ride.DeviceIotID, ride.VehicleID.String(), ride.UserID.String(),ride.AdditionComments)
}
```

and calling this function like this

```
func (p *RideRepositoryImpl) Save(ride *model.Ride, tx persistence.Transaction) error {
    return repository.Save(ride, p.insert, tx)
```

Now I want to get UUID of saved record instantly after saving this record . Is there any clean way to do this instantly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL has the [`RETURNING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/dml-returning.html) clause for this.

> Sometimes it is useful to obtain data from modified rows while they
> are being manipulated. The `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` commands
> all have an optional `RETURNING` clause that supports this. Use of
> `RETURNING` avoids performing an extra database query to collect the
> data, and is especially valuable when it would otherwise be difficult
> to identify the modified rows reliably.

```golang
// add the RETURNING clause to your INSERT query
sql := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES(%s) RETURNING <name_of_uuid_column>", TableName, strings.Join(Columns, ","), placeHolders)

// use QueryRow instead of Exec
row := tx.QueryRow(sql, ride.ID.String(), ride.DeviceIotID, ride.VehicleID.String(), ride.UserID.String(),ride.AdditionComments)

// scan the result of the query
var uuid string
if err := row.Scan(&uuid); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// ...
```

For additional INSERT-specific info related to `RETURNING` you can go to the [`INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html) documentation and search the page for "returning" with CTRL/CMD+F.

---

If, in addition, you need your function to still return an `sql.Result` value to satisfy some requirement, then you can return your own implementation.

```golang
var _ sql.Result = sqlresult{} // compiler check

type sqlresult struct { lastid, nrows int64 }

func (r sqlresult) LastInsertId() (int64, error) { return r.lastid, nil }
func (r sqlresult) RowsAffected() (int64, error) { return r.nrows, nil }

func (*RideRepositoryImpl) insert(entity interface{}, tx persistence.Transaction) (sql.Result, error) {
    ride := entity.(*model.Ride)

    placeHolders := repository.InsertPlaceholders(len(rideColumns))
    sql := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES(%s) RETURNING <name_of_uuid_column>", TableName, strings.Join(Columns, ","), placeHolders)
    row := tx.QueryRow(sql, ride.ID.String(), ride.DeviceIotID, ride.VehicleID.String(), ride.UserID.String(),ride.AdditionComments)
    if err := row.Scan(&ride.<NameOfUUIDField>); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return sqlresult{0, 1}, nil
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer sir , there is one issue  as you can see my Insert funciton I want to return  `(sql.Result, error) `  so in this case hoe I will return `(sql.Result, error)`  ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What do you need it for? If you need it to satisfy an interface then just return a `nil` `sql.Result`.

Comment: test have been written on basis of this returning . like its pre-implemented architecture for CRUD in app that I need  `(sql.Result, error)`  in return  which is default returning of  `tx.Exec`

Comment: @Ninja `sql.Result` is an interface, you can always return your own dummy implementation, very easy.

Comment: I can't get same result from `QueryRow` somehow ? As It may change other scenarios for insertions

Comment: I'm not exactly certain what you mean by that question. `QueryRow` returns an `*sql.Row`, Go is statically typed so you can't change `QueryRow` to instead return `sql.Result`. If the solution in the answer is not gonna work for you then you have to retrieve the uuid in a separate step, a second query, you won't be able to retrieve it immediately using only `Exec` (which is the *only* method that returns `sql.Result`).

Comment: @Ninja I've added an example of how you can return your own `sql.Result`, I'm not sure whether or not that satisfies your requirements, if not, then you might want to open a new question because the answer I've provided here is the recommended way to do what your original question requested.